# Problem - Reverse screen testing app on emulator android 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen

I just tested an app developed for Android 2.2 on the 3.2 emulator. The app supports only portrait mode, thus in default landscape mode of the emulator it's rotated by 90° (as on Android 2.2).
If however I rotate the emulator to portrait mode, the screen is shown completely reversed by 180°. That means, what should be on top is on the bottom of the screen. It's not only the app, but also the Android status bar but, if I exit the app, the issue disappears.
I've tested the app on several Phones and emulators, this never happened with Android 2.2 or 2.3 it just happens with 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2. Can't test on a real Tablet device yet. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post what's in your manifest file?

Comment: Posting your manifest will definitely help us help you. If you can create a dummy project with the same orientation parameters. Post a link to apk here, and I can test it on a tablet and let you know if this is just an emulator problem or if it exists on the real devices too.

Comment: hello! thanks to everyone for the help. 
My manifest file is in this link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11735620/AndroidManifest.xml
And the apk is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11735620/euroMilhoesApp.apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this from your activity in manifest file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```